# Ticks of varying sizes in R lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to plot a barchart and get tick marks at the 4 year marks with dates underneath them which I got but also smaller tickmarks indicating each quarter within every year.

```
barchart(V3~V1,  data = differences,origin=0,box.ratio=40, lty=0,reference=TRUE,stack=TRUE,par.settings=list (axis.text=list(cex=1.5), axis.line = list(lwd=3)),scales=list(y=list(tick.number=8, rot=90,alternating=1), x=list(at=c(6,18,30,42,54,66,78,90,102,114,126,138,150,162,174,186,198), labels=c("\n1996","","","","\n2000","","","","\n2004","","","","\n2008","","","","\n2012"),draw=TRUE,tck=1   )))
```

Here is some sample data

```
01/31/1996      -7.3667
02/29/1996       0.9413
03/31/1996       9.3252
04/30/1996       0.3147
05/31/1996       8.8593
06/30/1996      10.0297
07/31/1996       0.64i3
08/31/1996       2.1397
09/30/1996       0.6759
10/31/1996      -1.5579
11/30/1996       2.9493
....             ....
goes to 2012..
```

right now this gives

```
  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
1996            2000          2004 and so on
```

so I want the the x axis to look like

```
    |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
   1996            2000        2004 and so on

where | indicates tick of size 2 and | is size 1 for example
      |
```

how do you specify two ticks of different sizes at different intervals? Thanks.

update following MrFlick's comments

is there to use an ifelse statement for the tck for my current setup, something like

```
barchart(V3~V1,  data = differences,origin=0,box.ratio=40, lty=0,reference=TRUE,stack=TRUE,par.settings=list (axis.text=list(cex=1.5), axis.line = list(lwd=3)),scales=list(y=list(tick.number=8, rot=90,alternating=1), x=list(at=c(6,18,30,42,54,66,78,90,102,114,126,138,150,162,174,186,198), labels=c("\n1996","","","","\n2000","","","","\n2004","","","","\n2008","","","","\n2012"),draw=TRUE,tck=ifelse(some condition, 1,2   )))
```

where some condition can refer to the list of numbers 6,18,30,42,54,66,78,90,102,114,126,138,150,162,174,186,198 somehow.  Is it possible to pass this in as array somehow so tck can reference it.  Ie array[i] % 18 == 0, something like this where this tck is somehow iterating through a list

Comment: Yea that one was poorly phrased and tagged sorry

Comment: @niels It's better to edit existing posts than repost the same question with more detail. Please delete the other one or this will be marked as a duplicate and disappear.

Comment: You should be able to get working code that handles axis ticks at the Lattice (the book) website. Chapter 8 handles axis annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example showing how you can customize ticks. Here's some sample data

```
dd<-data.frame(
   V1=seq(as.Date("1996-01-31"), as.Date("2006-12-31"), by="1 mon"),
   V2=cumsum(rnorm(132))
)
```

And then we can plot that with

```
barchart(V2~V1, dd, horiz=F, xscale.components=function(...) {
    dp <- function(x,p) as.numeric(strftime(x, p))
    ans <- xscale.components.default(...)   
    dates <- as.POSIXct(ans$bottom$labels$labels)
    xf <- approxfun(as.numeric(dates), ans$bottom$labels$at)
    rng <- range(dates)
    if(dp(rng[1],"%d")!=1) {
        rng[1] <- seq(ISOdate(dp(rng[1],"%Y"), dp(rng[1],"%m"), 1), 
            length.out=2, by="1 mon")[2]
    }
    at.dates<-seq(rng[1], rng[2], by="1 mon")

    ats <- xf(at.dates)
    ans$bottom$ticks$at <- ats
    ans$bottom$ticks$tck <- ifelse(((dp(at.dates, "%m")-1) %% 3)==0, 2, 1)
    ans$bottom$labels$at <- ats
    ans$bottom$labels$labels <- ifelse(dp(at.dates, "%m")==1, dp(at.dates, "%Y"), " ")
    ans
}, lty=0, stack=T, origin=0, reference=T,
scales=list(x=list(draw=T, tck=1)))
```

Which produces

[image]

The first challenge is that `barchart()` expects a categorical axis so it doesn't like dates very much. (it would be a bit easier with `xyplot`). But basically we explicitly set the tick lengths and positions with `tck` and `at` respectively. If you vary the tick lengths, it can have unintended consequences on the labels unless they are the same length as the ticks so I just added in blank labels for the shorter ticks and plotted them at the same position. You can check out `?xscale.components.default` for more information.

This should be fairly robust for different date ranges but I haven't tested extensively.

Comment: Hi this is really cool thank you.  But can you explain what you're doing? I'm new to R and very confused about the notation

Comment: For ex. ans$bottom$labels$labels and ans$bottom$labels$at are used in the first portion before they are declared below.  What is ats.  I'm just confused about which are declared first and how they depend on each other.

Comment: This task did prove to be quite difficult so if you're new to R, I wouldn't worry too much about not understanding it all. But the basic idea is that we call `ans<-xscale.components.default(...)` first to get all the default settings for the axis annotations. Then this function transforms and replaces the default values with what we actually want. `ats` is numeric value of all the dates where I want to place tick marks. It tells you "at" which position to drak the tick.

Comment: It also looks like you might be somewhat new to SO as well. When someone provides an answer to your question that solves your problem, you should click the check mark next to the question to mark it as "correct" and close out the question (remove it from the unanswered list). If it doesn't solve the problem, it's best to let them know why in a comment.

Comment: OK I did. is there any way to use the ifelse in my original barchart, please check my orignal post which I edited.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you had to accept my answer, it just appeared that you've never accepted any answer before. If i thought it would have been possible to easily edit the scale parameter to accomplish this behavior, I would have. This is the only way I know how to accomplish what you've asked for. Your original strategy seemed to have many flaws in making assumptions about dates that I was uncomfortable with.

Comment: Oh I think you provided an excellent answer.  What kind of condition can I impose to only print 1996,2000,2004,2008,2012?

Comment: Right now the labels are placed when the month == 1 (January) in this line `ifelse(dp(at.dates, "%m")==1, dp(at.dates, "%Y"), " ")` You can also add something like and the year is divisible by 4 with `ifelse(dp(at.dates, "%m")==1 & dp(at.dates, "%Y") %% 4==0, dp(at.dates, "%Y"), " ")`

Comment: I do have monthly data so dd<-data.frame(
   V1=seq(as.Date("1996-01-31"), as.Date("2006-12-31"), by="1 mon"),
   V2=cumsum(rnorm(132))
) is correct, but I only want 4 tickmarks per year indicating quarters.  Is there a way to do this.  The year works great btw.

Comment: ALso is there a way to add spacing btw the ticks and years